# How to sum two columns containing null values in a dataframe in Spark/PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe in following format -

```
Col1    |cnt_Test1     |cnt_Test2
_______________________________________
Stud1   | null        | 2
Stud2   | 3           | 4
Stud3   | 1           | null
```

I want to create a new column by aggregating cnt_Test1 and cnt_Test2 to get the following result -

```
Col1    |cnt_Test1     |cnt_Test2     | new_Count
____________________________________________________
Stud1   | null        | 2              | 2
Stud2   | 3           | 4              | 7
Stud3   | 1           | null           | 1
```

However, I am getting the following output - where sum of a null and long integer is null

```
Col1    |cnt_Test1     |cnt_Test2     | new_Count
____________________________________________________
Stud1   | null        | 2              | null
Stud2   | 3           | 4              | 7
Stud3   | 1           | null           | null
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks, I did try to look it up before posting the question, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @AmitPandey if the given answer satisfies you question can you please accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `coalesce` function like below

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
("Stud1",None,2),
("Stud1",3,4),
("Stud1",1, None)], 
("col1","cnt_Test1", "cnt_Test2"))


# Import functions
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df1 = df.withColumn("new_count", f.coalesce(f.col('cnt_Test1'), f.lit(0)) + f.coalesce(f.col('cnt_Test2'), f.lit(0)))
```

Comment: What if I have want to sum columns in a list? How can I use it with coalesce?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it as a two step:

```
df2 = df.na.fill(0)
df2.withColumn("new_Count", df2["cnt_Test1"] + df2["cnt_Test2"]).show()
```

Comment: It would work, but then it would change the nature of the original data. The nulls have to be retained so that we can compute averages.